# Call Xib from Storyboard - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I am trying to launch a xib file through a storyboard.

Storyboard
`Main.storyboard`

Inside a touch event in the storyboard when clicking a button I have this

`GLViewController *viewController=[[GLViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GLViewController" bundle:nil]; [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

I renamed Xib file to `GlViewController.xib` same as Xib's ViewController class name.

Running I get error:

`Unknown class _TtC9MyApp16GLViewController in Interface Builder file.`
 `MyApp[92282:1995489] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<GLViewController 0x7f9f10420110> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.'`

however I have the GLViewController in the compile sources and I'm referecing it at the top of my  Storyboard's ViewController.

Comment: The nib file refers to an outlet called `delegate` in `GLViewController` but that class doesn't have that outlet.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually there but it's connected to File's Owner for some reason